# How to put the answer from recursive function in an array (PHP)?

Tags: php, arrays, function, recursion

there,

I tried many time to put the answer from the recursive function inside an array ($result) but I couldn't. Here the code:

```
function readDirs($path , $result = [])
{

    $dirHandle = opendir($path);
    while($item = readdir($dirHandle)) 
    {
       $newPath = $path."/".$item;
       if(is_dir($newPath) && $item != '.' && $item != '..') 
       { 
         readDirs($newPath, $result);
       }
       elseif(!is_dir($newPath) && $item != '.DS_Store' && $item != '.' && $item != '..')
       { 
          echo "$path<br>";
          $result[] = $path;
          return $result;
       }
    }
}
            
$path =  "/Users/mycomputer/Documents/www/Photos_projets";
$results = array();
readDirs($path, $results);
```

Can you help me to put the path inside the array, because I need them later in my code?
Thank's

Comment: The most obvious thing is that you’re not using `readDirs()` to assign a variable. A good first step would be `$result = readDirs($path);`.

Comment: Try and pass the `$results` array as a reference by changing `readDirs($path , $result = [])` to `readDirs($path , &$result)`. Then you don't need to return it. The outer `$results` will be populated after the function call.

Answer (score 0):

I cant understand your question but for sure this may be help

```
 function readDirs($path)
{
    $result = [];
    $dirHandle = opendir($path);
    while($item = readdir($dirHandle)) 
    {
       $newPath = $path."/".$item;
       if(is_dir($newPath) && $item != '.' && $item != '..') 
       { 
         $result[] = readDirs($newPath);
       }
       elseif(!is_dir($newPath) && $item != '.DS_Store' && $item != '.' && $item != '..')
       { 
          echo "$path<br>";
          $result[] = $path;
          return $result; //im not sure this return statement you implement is needed try it to remove it if this does not work
       }
    }
   return $result;
}

$path =  "/Users/mycomputer/Documents/www/Photos_projets";
$result = readDirs($path);
var_dump($result);
```

try it and response.

Comment: was a pleasure but pleas close the question if your question was answered.